# How do I turn the toString of an object type interface so I can get the path to load the user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, interface, user-controls

Currently my program gets a list of search types and then creates an instance of each type and fills it with data. My problem is taking instance and displaying it/giving a path to load the control. soType.toString() currently returns: "WebApplication1.View.customerCardUserControl" ....which would be the dot notation of the path to that user control.

```
List<SearchObjectType> searchTypes = SearchXMLParser.GetSearchTypes();
SearchObjectType sot = searchTypes[0];
ICard soType = sot.InstantiateSearchObject();
    foreach (DataResult data in dataList)
    {
       soType.Populate(data); //this is what I want put in the listView
       ListView1.Controls.Add(WHAT DO I PUT HERE?!?);
```

Comment: What do you *want* to display?

Comment: ToString() will not work, you need to add  reference to an instance of a control

Comment: Doesn't a `ListView` allow an `Enumerable`, why can't you apply your `List` as a data source then use the natural search and sort capabilities of the control?

Comment: I want to display every user control with its associated data for every data object I have. soType.Populate(data) is taking the data from the data object and plugging it into the associated user control of the soType, which could be 1 of 3 usercontrols.

Comment: @ChrisBint the idea is that you dont necessarily KNOW the reference to the instance of the user control. The XML has a list of all possible datatypes and soType will be an instance of each one of those types. This is why I cant directly reference the user control in this code. I have to grab it from somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I take the SearchObjectType you wrote your self, you can then override the tostring() method like so

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return "not the path"
    }
```

this should give you some idea :) good luck